# reading .sec format video opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm dealing with .sec file format videos (samsung camera backup files). Each backup folder contains an .exe application to playback those backups. Those backups come in two ways; single camera backup and multible (multible positions at same place) cameras backups as well. The one camera backup frames been captured successfully bt opencv, yet the multiple cameras didn't. I have noticed couple of points as:

- The single camera videos frames always exist, yet the multiple cameras do not (motion detection activated?).
- The .exe file of the multiple cameras do play all video ones.
- The cap variable (cv2.VideoCapture) for those files (.sec) do not accept setting parameters (cap.set() returns fasle).

I have used an app called "MediaInfo.exe" to get info about those files as:

the single camera:
[image]

the multiple camers:
[image]

What i'm looking for is to reach a success capturing one (or more) of the multiple cameras backups.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

It seems the proplem is not clear, so here is the code i have:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('a_file_from_single_camera_backup.sec')
ret, frame = cap.read()
print(ret, frame)
```

output:

```
True [[[132 140 130][133 141 131][134 142 132]...[ 60  51  43][ 60  51  43][ 60  51  43]]...
```

and

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('a_file_from_multiple_cameras_backup.sec')
ret, frame = cap.read()
print(ret, frame)
```

output:

```
False None
```

and

```
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'))
```

output: (for both files)

```
False
```

Comment: Videocapture read do not retrieve from the .sec files of the multiple cameras backups (Null frames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who is facing an issue reading the .sec (samsun security camera backup) file format using opencv, there are two scenario as (in my case):

- The backup belongs to a one camera (one position) that can be read by
  opencv correctly (need to do nothing). You just need to know that the
  vid comes in h.264 codec.
- The backup belongs to multiple cameras (multiple positions) which
  won't be read by opencv, yet you can change the file extension from
  .sec to .hevc so the opencv will do the job. Also, you need to know
  that the vid is h.265 codec as well.

for more, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding

Good luck!